# Mongodb on Server running very slow

Tags: mongodb

I am  using mongodb version 3.4 on the server. Mongo logs are showing that my aggregate queries are taking around 108ms time to execute.

```
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:2263 hasSortStage:1 numYields:19 nreturned:0 reslen:50
```

This is a plan summary from one of such query. Can anyone tell me if it's ok with this query or its taking too much time.

Also I am not using cursor in aggregate. So there's this error

```
> Use of the aggregate command without the 'cursor' option is
> deprecated. See
> http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/aggregate-without-cursor-deprecation.
```

However the queries are running fine.

I have hosted my server on Amazon AWs with 1 GB ram explicitly for Mongodb.

While running such queries, its taking 99% of the CPU.

Can the use of 'cursor' fix it?

CPU consumption is going Abnormally high (99.7%) while running these queries. Even a single query is tasking this much processing, slowing down the portions of website where Mongo is used.

Comment: You need to increase RAM.

Comment: HI Saleem thanks for replying, My CPU consumption is very high, while running the quires however the RAM stays at 448 MB out of 1GB. What if I update my RAM now and after sometime same problem encounter again?

Comment: @Saleem Do you have any technical reason to explain that I need to increase RAM?